# Hyper ledger fabric-channel creation Node SDK -Error

Tags: node.js, sdk, hyperledger-fabric

Im trying to create a channel using node SDK and get the following error.

```
Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: Orderer with name:orderer.example.com not found
```

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess but you chang the `exapmle` to `example`.

Apart from that, the Error means the SDK cannot communicate with the Orderer. Either it is not up or it is known by a different url.

Comment: Sorry, It was a type mistake actually.i edited it now .Expecting a solution thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The orderer is not up.

The best thing you can do it to set the logging level for the orderer to DEBUG and check is logs.
It is crashing for some reason, you can see the logs and try to understand what happens.
If you post here the logs I'm happy to hlelp you.